# Bulk Insert Update ON Sql Azure

Tags: azure-sql-database

I have 15 Millions Records  need to insert  and update  on Hourly Bases on Sql Azure.  when executing the query in Sql Azure DataBase  it throughing TCP IP Error after 1 Hour . but when used same query sql server 2008 R2 it's working fine and take approx 10 Min.

when 15 Millions Records partially executed on Sql Azure then take much more time. so please suggest better way how to proceed this Records.

Thanx

Nirmit

Answer (score 0):

What is your performance tier for SQL-Azure currently set to and what kind of server is 2008-R2 Running on?

I would honestly recommend trying Azure Data Factory instead.